# FactoryBot associations with camcelCase ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot

Is there a way to use a camelCase ID for the factorybot association?

I've used `association :this_is_my_user, factory: :user` to define custom indexs before but it always expects a `_id` which is the rails convention. I'm using a table that was not originally defined by rails which is why I'm bumping into this issue.

```
Animals
- id
- name

AnimalLocations
- id
- animalId
- name
```

I've tried
`association :animal, factory: :animal`

and I've tried the before hook

```rb
factory :animal_location, :class => AnimalLocation do
    id { SecureRandom.uuid }

    before :create do |animal_location|
      animal = create :animal
      animal_location.animalId = animal.id
    end

  end
```

but I'm still receiving

```rb
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Animal must exist
```

Not really sure how to property associate these two models with factorybot if nether of these work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you try using different name in your `before :create` statement? Like `before :create do |temp_animal_location| do ... end`.

Comment: did you try just using `animal`? https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: And you really want to get rid of `id { SecureRandom.uuid }`. FactoryBot will handle stubbing ids when you use `FactoryBot.build_stubbed` and when you use `FactoryBot.create` this will mess up the actual id assignment done by the model.